# Scroll when dragging beyond the top or the left border

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I am developing a graph editor and have a problem with scroll when dragging beyond the top or the left border. When I drag node down or to the right it works. XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <GraphSpace />
</ScrollViewer>
```

GraphSpace extended Canvas.
In GraphSpace overloaded MeasureOverride:

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);

        double width = base
        .InternalChildren
        .OfType<UIElement>()
        .Max(i => i.DesiredSize.Width + (double)i.GetValue(GraphArea.XProperty) + 20);

    double height = base
        .InternalChildren
        .OfType<UIElement>()
        .Max(i => i.DesiredSize.Height + (double)i.GetValue(GraphArea.YProperty) + 20);

    return new Size(width, height);
}
```

How can I fix it?